# I processed fingerprints. How do I compare the resuts?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, comparison, fingerprint

**I'm a trying to compare fingerprints. Here's what I got so far.**

1. Get the raw image from a digitalPersona sensor. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3kXj.jpg)
2. Binarize it. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbEDP.jpg)
3. Skeletonize it. I used Hall's algorithm because that is the only one I got to work more or less properly. You can still see some flaws. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpCZw.jpg)
4. Strip the convex hull (inverted Jarvis algorithm) and get all the ridge endings as an array of (i, j) coordinates (points with one neighbour only). I also have a script to get the bifurcations (3 neighbours). [representation of ridge endings only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MahkG.jpg)

**What I need :** knowing that I can get these so-called minutiae (ridge endings and also bifurcations, which are not represented on the image) and also a direction for each point (e.g. direction of ridge for the ridge ending), how do I match two sets of minutiae and give a similarity score ?

**Tools and languages used:** digitalParsona U.are.U 4500 scanner, fprint library on linux, C for image aquisition, Python3 with PIL for image processing.

**My thoughts so far :**

- I can neglect  the finger rotation for now, but I probably need to normalize the sets to compensate the (x, y) shifts between two images of the same finger.
- Maybe I could transform the sets so that they have the same barycenter, but I don't know how well that will work.
- I could create a matrix of intensities for each set (e.g 5 on a point, 4 around the point, etc) so as to get something that could be represented like [this but with more spikes (best image I could find right now)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAiSL.png) and if A minus B gives me a pretty flat surface (mathematically, that could be a low sum of squares of values in the resulting matrix) I will know that the images look alike.

**How do you think I could compare to such sets ?**

I tried to show you that I really did put some effort in this and am not trying to get you to do the work for me ;)

If you have any questions I'll be happy to answer them. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Maybe search for similar minutia triangles that have no other minutiae points in them. Similarity is determined by triangle side length ratios. When you find one similar triangle try to incorporate to the match more minutiae that can build more similar triangles.

Comment: Interesting, would you mind to elaborate a bit on that ?

Answer (score 1):

The critical thing to realize is that your first steps are anything but exact. You will have errors in finding ridge endings and bifurcations.

However, not all errors are equally likely. A quick glance told me that a ridge ending too close to another ridge might be misclassified as a bifurcation, which is a qualitative error. A second expected error would be to misplace the ridge ending along the ridge. However, the error orthogonal to the ridge likely is small. You might also miss a few.

So, ignoring the orientation and offset problems, each minutia in one image should be paired with a minutia in the other image, based on approximate location. To do so, define a likelihood function on a pair of minutia, based on their distance, local ridge direction, type (ending/bifurcation). Iteratively form pairs between the two images, matching the most likely points, until they become too unlikely.

The first few pairs will give you a good estimate of the typical distances; this can also be used to refine the image offset estimations. Local ridge direction estimates *near minutiae* are probably not reliable to estimate orientation.

When all likely pairs are matched up, their associated likelihoods can be combined to come up with a combined likelihood that the two sets of minutiae match.

On a side note, the whole notion of minutiae appears to me as a legacy from older manual fingerprint matching techniques. Personally the first step I'd do would be to take the gradients of the greyscale image, and look for ridges *and valleys* in the gradient field. And instead of looking for the minutiae, I'd be looking at points in the image where the direction of the gradient (modulo 180 degrees) is quickly varying.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do realize this is by no means exact, which is why I want to give a resemblance score more than a definitive answer. So what you are suggesting is to make a function that compares two points and to determine the most likely match for each point ? I've tried something like that but have encountered the problem of the offset.

Comment: As to the gradient thing, I can see how that would give me the ridges and valleys, but how would I compare two such maps ? By matching the points where the gradient "turns" ? Do you think that would be less error-prone ? (I honestly don't mean to seem critical btw, you make some great points)

Comment: @Ghuizing: The pairwise likelihood function is a building block, but it's not the only one. You first need to estimate the rotation and offset to match the two images, but you would use a generic (non-fingerprint specific) algorithm for that. E.g. OpenCV `matchTemplate`. As for finding pairs, you start by taking the closest pair. Calculate the likelihood of that pair, then calculate the maximum distance at which another point could still be a better match (because it would have a better match on ridge direction etc). This is the neighborhood to check.

Comment: @Ghuizing: As for the gradient method, you might want to try it. Generate a false-color image where the hue corresponds to the gradient direction (modulo 180 degrees). I predict you see large swaths of almost the same color, with sudden color changes at a few points. You can even overlay your skeleton from step 3. to see the correspondence. This seems far more robust, because pressing your finger harder on the sensor does not affect the gradients, but it will affect ridge ending positions. (or turn them into bifurcations)

Comment: I see. If I don't get results with the method I am using right now I will try the gradient approach, thanks. I have seen loads of fingerprint-related implementations with OpenCV. I'm looking at that specific function's documentation but I don't really understand what it does