# Minutiae-based fingerprint matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix, fingerprint, biometrics

**The problem**

*I need to match two fingerprints and give a score of resemblance.*

I have posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120120/i-processed-fingerprints-how-do-i-compare-the-resuts) before, but I think I've made enough progress to warrant a new question.

**The input**

For each image, I have a list of minutiae (important points). I want to match the fingerprints by matching these two lists.

When represented graphically, they look like this:

[image: minutiae]

A minutia consists of a triplet `(i, j, theta)` where:

- `i` is the row in a matrix
- `j` is the column in a matrix
- `theta` is a direction. I don't use that parameter yet in my matching algorithm.

**What I have done so far**

- *For each list, find the "dense regions" or "clusters"*. Some areas have more points than others, and I have written an algorithm to find them. I can explain further if you want.
- *Shifting the second list* in order to account for the difference in finger position between both images. I neglect differences in finger rotation. The shift is done by aligning the barycenters of the centers of the clusters. (It is more reliable than the barycenter of all minutiae)
- I tried building a matrix for each list (post-shift) so that for every minutia increments the corresponding element and it's close neighbours, like below.

  `1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

  `1 2 2 2 2 2 1`

  `1 2 3 3 3 2 1`

  `1 2 3 4 3 2 1`

  `1 2 3 3 3 2 1`

  `1 2 2 2 2 2 1`

  `1 1 1 1 1 1 1`
- By subtracting the two matrices and adding up the absolute values of all elements in the resulting matrix, I hoped to get low numbers for close fingerprints.

**Results**

- I tested a few fingerprints and found that the number of clusters is very stable. Matching fingerprints very often have the same number of clusters, and different fingers give different numbers. So that will definitely be a factor in the overall resemblance score.
- The sum of the differences didn't work at all however. There was no correlation between resemblance and the sum.

**Thoughts**

- I may need to use the directions of the points but I don't know how yet
- I could use the standard deviation of the points, or of the clusters.
- I could repeat the process for different types of minutiae. Right now my algorithm detects ridge endings and ridge bifurcations but maybe I should process these separately.

**Question: How can I improve my algorithm ?**

**Edit**

I've come a long way since posting this question, so here's my update.

I dropped the bifurcations altogether, because my thinning algorithm messes those up too often. I did however end up using the angles quite a lot.

My initial cluster-counting idea does hold up pretty well on the small scale tests I ran (different combinations of my fingers and those of a handful of volunteers).

I give a score based on the following tests (10 tests, so 10% per success. It's a bit naïve but I'll find a better way to turn these 10 results into a score, as each test has its specificities):

- Cluster-thingy (all the following don't use clusters, but minutiae. This is the only cluster-related approach I took)
- Mean `i` position
- Mean angle
- `i` variance
- `j` variance
- Angle variance
- `i` kurtosis
- `j` kurtosis
- Angle kurtosis
- `j` skewness

A statistical approch indeed.

Same finger comparisons give pretty much always between 80 and 100%. Odd finger comparisons between 0 and 60% (not often 60%). I don't have exact numbers here so I won't pretend this a statistically significant success but it seems like a good first shot.

Comment: I realize it's a long post, I tried to be as specific as possible, and to show the research I have done. There's more details about the basics of my algorithm in the link I gave. *Thanks for reading!*

Comment: 1. In your diagram, I can't tell if you're showing 1 or 2 images, and, if 2, which are they? 2. When apologizing for a long post, it's [customary to add a potato](https://acumagnet.wordpress.com/2014/12/29/sorry-for-the-long-post-heres-a-potato-comes-from-glados-in-portal-2/) :-)

Comment: I'm showing one image. It's just a sample to give an idea of how the points are spaced.

Comment: Oh, and have a [potato](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iur/?f=1&image_host=http%3A%2F%2Fcitizenpotato.files.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F08%2Fpotato.jpg&u=https://citizenpotato.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/potato.jpg) then ;)

Comment: I would try the following: first, reduce each set of n points to the list of all O(n^2) pairwise distances between them, sorted by increasing distance.  To compare two fingerprints, you could find, for each distance in one list its "nearest neighbour" in the other; the score is the number of distances that "choose each other" as their nearest neighbours.  (This can be done with a list merge in time linear in the size of the list, which is O(n^2) in the original problem.)  Compare scores between many pairs of known-same and known-different fingerprints to choose an appropriate threshold.

Comment: @j_random_hacker thanks for your input! I remember trying something similar a while ago. I will definitely try again, but how would you account for outliers far from the other points thus matched while if there were more points they wouldn't? Maybe a maximal distance? And doesn't high density of points favorise false matches too?

Comment: There are a variety of measures that you could make that are all based on this idea.  Yes, I think choosing some maximum distance could help, though it would be even better if there were some way to avoid making such a possibly arbitrary choice.  In the end there can be the potential for both false positive and false negative matches, which is why you'll need a regression (machine learning) step to figure out a suitable threshold.

Answer (score 3):

Your clustering approach is interesting, but one thing I'm curious about is how well you've tested it.  For a new matching algorithm to be useful with respect to all the research and methods that already exists, you need to have a reasonably low EER.  Have you tested your method with any of the standard databases?  I have doubts as to the ability of cluster counts and locations alone to identify individuals at larger scales.

1) Fingerprint matching is a well studied problem and there are many good papers that can help you implement this.  For a nice place to start, check out this paper, ["Fingerprint Minutiae Matching Based on the Local and Global Structures"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/906252/?tp=&arnumber=906252) by Jiang & Yau.  It's a classic paper, a short read (only 4 pages), and can be implemented fairly reasonably.  They also define a scoring metric that can be used to quantify the degree to which two fingerprint images match. Again, this should only be a starting point because these days there are many algorithms that perform better.

2) If you want your algorithm to be robust, it should consider transformations of the fingerprint between images.  Scanned fingerprints and certainly latent prints may not be consistent from image to image.

Also, calculating the direction of the minutiae points provides a method for handling fingerprint rotations.  By measuring the angles between minutiae point directions, which will remain the same or close to the same across multiple images regardless of global rotation (though small inconsistencies may occur because skin is not rigid and may stretch slightly), you can find the best set of corresponding minutia pairs or triplets and use them as the basis for rotational alignment.

3) I recommend that you distinguish between ridge line endings and bifurcations.  The more features you can isolate, the more accurately you can determine whether or not the fingerprints match.  You might also consider the number of ridge lines that occur between each minutiae point.

This image below illustrates the features used by Jiang and Yau.
[image: Global and Local Features (Jiang & Yau, 2000)]

- d: Euclidean distance between minutiae
- θ: Angle measure between minutiae directions
- φ: Global minutiae angle
- n: Number of ridge lines between minutiae i and j

If you haven't read the [Handbook of Fingerprint Recognition](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=1Wpx25D8qOwC&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=handbook%20of%20fingerprint%20recognition&ots=9xS-3Vlx77&sig=qdYH8iOfozhDbaa0Mp3gbtRSwHk#v=onepage&q=handbook%20of%20fingerprint%20recognition&f=false), I recommend it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, also these links seem quite useful! My questions was posted some time ago so I've progressed a bit since. To clarify, I'm not trying to build something as good as existing algorithms, I'm merely fiddling with Python image manipulations for a school project. If my algorithm is good enough to protect your computer from your 10 yo nephew I'll consider it a success ;) I'm editing my question with an update and I'll try to react on some of your ideas. Thanks again!

Comment: A cluster based approch is indeed a bit weak because much information is lost in the process. But I try to get a diverse range of values ("tests") out of my image and compare those.

Comment: Well, in that case let me just throw out this idea.  When I was looking at minutiae points one day in an image like the one you show, I had the thought of using minimum spanning trees to create a simple matching algorithm.  Then maybe you could match prints based on overlapping subtrees.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I don't have much time left to finish the project, but I'll look into minimum spanning trees when I'm on my computer